# add background image to UITableViewController in Navigation based app

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimage, uitableview

I have a navigation based app where I push `UITableViewControllers` onto the stack.  I would like to add a background `UImage` to all of my `UITableViewControllers`.  Not a `UIColor`, but an `UImage`.  I know how I can do this using a `Nib` file and setting the `UITableView` itself to have use `[UIColor ClearColor]`, but I don't want to go through all my `UITableViewControllers` and change them to using `Nib` files, etc.

I also found [this solution](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/03/how-to-add-a-nice-background-image-to-your-grouped-table-view/) which would be great if I was just using a single tableviewcontroller in my app.  I think there might be a way to make this work, by adding a subview "below" my table view that is created by default in a `UITableViewController`?

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's a little different in a navigation based app: just change the background of the navigation view that each table view is sitting on. Placing the following code in `viewDidLoad` of each UITableViewController works:

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = 
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But you may only need to do it once, at the top level of the navigation controller, rather than in each tableview controller (although you'll still have to set each background to clear).

Comment: In addition I needed a 3rd line: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: This doesn't push the background image down to the bottom of a nav bar like a viewcontroller does...

Comment: I am using this in my tableVC: [self.tableView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]]];
works like a charm ;)

Comment: New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520585/how-do-i-add-background-image-to-a-grouped-style-uitableviewcontroller-in-ios-6

Comment: @SteveMoser I added the iOS Solution to this question

Answer (score 16):

On iOS6 use this:

```
UIImageView *boxBackView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TextureBoxboard.jpg"]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:boxBackView];
```

Comment: why iOS6? `@property(nonatomic, readwrite, retain) UIView *backgroundView NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2); // the background view will be automatically resized to track the size of the table view.  this will be placed as a subview of the table view behind all cells and headers/footers.  default may be non-nil for some devices.`

Comment: Yes, I know. But the other solution that is mentioned here is not working on iOS6 and this solution was buggy on < 4 I think. I tried it before, but it did not work. Don't know when this exactly was fixed tho.

Answer (score 2):

If your class is a UIViewController subclass then you can do it like this:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:
     [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
      [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
       [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:
        @"background.png"]]]];
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's actually the crux of my question.  It is not a UIViewController - it is a UITableViewController.

Comment: what tutorial are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = 
  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 
                                  0, 
                               self.navigationController.view.frame.size.width, 
                               self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height);
backgroundView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.navigationController.view insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
[backgroundView release];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

As Gorm said

> only need to do it once, at the top level of the `UINavigationController`

Answer (score 1):

The answer given my Madhup is the correct answer. UITableViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, so adding that to your UITableViewController's viewDidLoad method works great.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 3.2, `-[UITableView setBackgroundView:]` exists, which may be easier than some of the other proposed solutions going forward.