# How do I add a background image to a grouped style UITableViewController in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, ios6

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fullscreen-bg.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

That code worked fine in iOS 5 but it doesn't work in iOS 6. In iOS 6 it just show the default pinstriped background. Any ideas?

Comment: Also I found that original code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813846/add-background-image-to-uitableviewcontroller-in-navigation-based-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the image as a background view

```
[tableView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```

And That's it

Answer (score 6):

```
// FOR iOS 5
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.opaque = NO;

// FOR iOS 6
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Comment: Setting the tableView background color does work for grouped style table views. You end up with shadows all over the background.